# VLC keeps freezing my whole system

Tags: 20.04, snap, vlc

Whenever I try to watch multiple videos simultaneously using VLC, my whole system (Ubuntu 20.04) freezes and I have to restart to continue working.

Comment: Did you install VLC with snap like you tagged the question? Maybe try to install via `apt` and check again.

Comment: Have you ever tried to watch multiple on VLC before. I found it does not handle that well.

Comment: Does it freeze immediately, or after a certain amount of time?